# Java Spring не удается запустить @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring

У меня три класса. Пытаюсь подключить @PropertySource в проекте, но в файле application.properties данные не активны и spring их не подхватывает. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?
[image: Project structure]

Main

```java
package reversbot;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import reversbot.services.VkBot;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext (InjectionContext.class);
        VkBot vkBot = context.getBean(VkBot.class);
        vkBot.hello();
    }

}
```

InjectionContext

```java
package reversbot;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import reversbot.services.VkBot;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:resources/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class InjectionContext {

    @Bean
    public VkBot vkBot() {

        return new VkBot();
    }
}
```

VkBot

```java
package reversbot.services;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;


@Service

public class VkBot {

    @Value("$(ide)")
    String ide;

    @Value("$(token)")
    String token;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    @PostConstruct
    public void hello(){

        System.out.println ("Hello BOSS!!!!");
        System.out.println("ide = " + ide);
        System.out.println("token = " + token);
        System.out.println("        ");
    }

}
```

```
ide = login
token = 12345678
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Внедрение значений свойств

- не `@Value("$(ide)")`, а  `@Value("${ide}")`
- не `@Value("$(token)")`, a `@Value("${token}")`

Нужно использовать фигурные скобки, а не круглые

```java
@Service
public class VkBot {

    @Value("${ide}")
    String ide;

    @Value("${token}")
    String token;
   // ...
```

## 2. Путь к файлу со свойствами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Папка `resources` и так находится в `classpath`, поэтому указывать указывать `classpath:resources/application.properties` не стоит.
Когда вы делаете это, то фактически пытаетесь сослаться на следующий файл:
*src/main*/**resources/resources**/*application.properties*
Которого Spring не находит.

Поэтому лишнее упоминание папки `resources` стоит **убрать**

```java
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

## Итого

InjectionContext

```java
package reversbot;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import reversbot.services.VkBot;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class InjectionContext {

    @Bean
    public VkBot vkBot() {

        return new VkBot();
    }
}
```

VkBot

```java
package reversbot.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Service
public class VkBot {

    @Value("${ide}")
    String ide;

    @Value("${token}")
    String token;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    @PostConstruct
    public void hello(){
        System.out.println ("Hello BOSS!!!!");
        System.out.println("ide = " + ide);
        System.out.println("token = " + token);
        System.out.println("        ");
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, это работает.

Comment: @bodrovdeni, искренне рад. "Спасибо" тут принято "галочками" и "плюсиками" выражать. Подобные же комментарии(Спасибо) могут просто удалить как не несущие никакой смысловой нагрузки

Answer (score 0):

@PropertySource("application.properties") этого достаточно, но редактор может не подхватить или не сразу подхватить, при первом подключение проперти файлов, но это уже другой вопрос, проверьте есть ли  реальный доступ